# Checking all 100 km routes through network for proximity to facilities?

Tags: route, network-analysis

I am only interested in software agnostic answers to this question.

We're making a coverage analysis where we need to find out which sections of a road network are covered by EV charging capabilities. Initially we did a Service Area analysis in which all sections within 100 km (along a road network) from a charging station are considered covered and the rest not covered.

Thinking about what this means for users, however, lead us to consider the scenario illustrated below.

There, a charging station (filled red) is located along a road (black) less than 100 km from a T-intersection. A car driving along the road passing straight through the T-intersection (along the blue line) will be on a road considered to be covered (red) by the charging network while still not ever having passed a charging station.

[image]

To figure out which parts of the street network lacks coverage in a way that's useful to drivers, we're instead considering an analysis in which all possible 100 km routes through the network are checked for adjacency to the charging stations. This will give each point along the road network a degree of coverage depending on the ratio of covered and non-covered routes passing it.

Is there another way to think about the problem?

The network consists of about 500 polylines and there are about 100 charging stations included in the analysis.

Comment: Sorry. At this stage, we were thinking more generally about the problem because we didn't know what to try in the different applications. Googling this doesn't come up with any relevant suggestions for methods. We have manged to come up with another way to think about the problem, though, that provides a path forward with any of the applications. Is there a way for me to clarify that I'm interested in more general, than app-specific, answers, or do such questions not belong in this forum? I intend to post the answer myself but seem unable to do that now because of the hold.

Comment: Questions that are software agnostic can certainly be asked on this focused Q&A site but it is not designed to be a discussion forum. Personally, I think a question phrased in terms of something that you have tried using a particular software is easier to do and more likely to attract potential answerers than a question from which software has been abstracted. I'll remove your software references so that this may be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two problems here, not one:

Scenario:

a) Have a Graph (road network)

b) Have charging stations(points)

c)You need a path (set of edges) to calculate distances, from the EV to charging stations(points). At the end you will need to calculate every possible path of the graph(to avoid exponential problem , in each iteration exclude visited cities ).

These distances c*harging station to the charging station*, should never be more than 100km.
But **EV can’t fly** so, to calculate the distances you must **use the edges distances of the graph to reach the charging stations**.

**First problem**, would be to **consider only charging stations(points). That intersect the path (with some tolerance)**, so that you don’t have to go backwards.

**Second problem**, would be to **consider any charging stations(points). Even if you must go backwards** (could be some distance limit).

**The First problem:**

Load the data as shapefile or postgis in [**QGIS**](https://www.qgis.org)  and use [**Networkx**](https://networkx.github.io/) (both python)
**Networkx** library is the most complete library for Graphs, and will help tremendously in the task.

Just with Qgis there are some approaches:

Split path with charging stations(points).

Every resulting Split-path with length >100km is out of the Service Area.

**Second problem**:

Is not suitable for long distances (means more time) **from one city to another city**.

Could be suitable for short distances, like **inside a city**.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to think up a solution ourselves that should work:

1. Buffer charging station points with some distance (2 km)
2. Cut away parts of the street network that are within the buffer
3. Run a find-all-routes-between-network-endpoints algorithm. (Since the buffer-clip makes the network very fragmented, this kind of otherwise potentially too large calculation is now possible.
4. When all routes are found (no u-turns allowed) and turned into polylines, it's just a matter of isolating routes longer than 100 km. These represent possible routes one can drive without running into charging stations within 100 km.

Comment: Just a comment: The charging stations must been at most, at 50meters from the path, it could be a river or some obstacle(wall, woods, etc)that makes no possible for the EV, to go from the path to the charging station.